# GitHub Pages custom domain not showing HTTPS certificate for non apex domain

Tags: https, dns, github-pages

I'm trying to set up a custom domain for my GitHub Page.
So I bought a domain name from GoDaddy and I followed GitHub docs to set the custom domain (setting DNS records, writing the CNAME file and enforcing HTTPS on repo settings).
Everything seems to be okay and it works well:

[image: GitHub settings]

[image: DNS settings on GoDaddy admin panel]

[image: And the page is served over HTTPS correctly]

But when I type in the browser the *non-apex* domain or click on a link that contains https prefix [ https://www.omnivors.xyz ] the certificate appear to be invalid.
This does not happen if the link has *http* prefix: [ http://www.omnivors.xyz ], cause the site is redirected to the apex page.

What can I do to solve this problem?
(Here's the [repository](https://github.com/Omnivors/omnivors.github.io))

Thank you so much,
Francesco